# Background transparancy of a textfield

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitextfield

I have an application that contains a textfield.

Is there a way to change background transparency of this textfield in code?

Comment: what you want???background color with clear color??

Comment: yes exactly i don't want any background color

Comment: then use this code i paste code bellow with ClearColor see bellow my code with clearColor :)

Comment: [yourTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

Comment: To add to Nirav Mehta response, Swift 4 has an inference component on UIColor To save a few key strokes, you could also try the following code in your viewDidLoad or where ever you need the code. `yourTextField.backgroundColor = .clear`

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do it.

You can set transparency by setting its alpha. You can pic color code with digital color meter ( its a inbuilt application in mac).

if you set alpha 1 then there will be no transparency. set transparency according to your need (set alpha less then 1).

Try this:

```
textfield.backgroundColor=[[UIColor colorWithRed:208.0/255.0 green:15.0/255.0 blue:202.0/255.0 alpha:0.6] CGColor];
```

Comment: hey friend if you want to background transparent or clear the setBackground color with clearColor only just one simple line code dude...like ..[yourTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];      :)

Comment: @ParasJoshi You are correct about the simplicity of using clearColor, however this is still a good example. This answer is a great summary of basic color operations for the asker. +1 for both of you!

Answer (score 2):

You can set with below mentioned code in Xamarin

```
txtNumber.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
txtNumber.Alpha = 0.5f;
```

Reference 1: [transparent UITextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3428498/transparent-uitextview)
Reference 2: [How do I create a transparent UITextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4603084/how-do-i-create-a-transparent-uitextfield)

Similary:

txtNumber.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;

Answer (score 1):

Just put bellow code for white background

```
[yourTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
```

or if want to clear Color then bellow code

```
 [yourTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

so simple

:)

Answer (score 1):

use [Custom UITextField](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextField_Class/Reference/UITextField.html)

```
UITextField *yourTextField= [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
yourTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleNone;
[yourTextField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

Comment: refer [Custom UITextField](http://www.roseindia.net/answers/viewqa/Mobile-Applications/15639-UITextField-Programmatically-iPhone.html)